ubuntu runs from thumb drive but won't run from hard drive
computer is Dell inspiron with 1Tb hard drive.  Win 8.1 was installed but I wiped the disk before trying to install ubuntu. after booting from thumb drive, ubuntu runs fine asks if i want to install.  Checked yes but when I restart, screen asks to install bootable drive.  Cant seem to find the hard drive. Ubuntu is 24.04.01 LTS  bios: usb boot support [enabled], secure boot start [disabled], load legacy OPROM [enabled],boot mode [UEFI], 1st boot device [internal HDD devices], 2nd boot device [usb storage device], 3rd boot device [ internal ODD device],4th boot device [usb floppy device], 5th boot device [onboard NIC device].  I followed the instructions on removing the boot thumb device when Ubuntu asked me to, still no luck.

You've not provided your Ubuntu product & release details; and as different Ubuntu products & releases use different installers; we can't know yet what you tried. The asking to install again after reboot implies to me you also didn't remove your installation media (your machine firmware/BIOS settings control boot order; not the OS on devices), so did you follow instructions for your unstated Ubuntu product & unstated release?

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
